# Securely store in app purchase data locally

Tags: ios, security, in-app-purchase, store

I'm currently working on an ios application that includes in app purchases.
At the moment i store the purchased product identifiers in a file in the Documents folder.
i assumed that that directory isn't available to users but i was informed that some pc applications are able to access that directory.

Does anyone have a suggestion to securely store the data on the device?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the keychain to store secured data.

http://dev-metal.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/howto-use-keychain-in-iphone-sdk-to.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to have a look at this post:

http://maniacdev.com/2011/12/tutorial-securing-ios-app-data-using-the-data-protection-api-keychain-and-cryptography/

It is a tutorial divided in two parts with practical examples.

Greetings,

Fabio
@fcerullo